# JS/jQuery/mootools detect broswer supports HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, mootools

How do I detect if a browser supports HTML5 by

JS

(or)

jquery AND mootools.

Comment: Can we stick to JS/JQ/Mootools? Thanks.

Comment: HTML5 has many features. Some browsers implement some of them, some don't. What particular features do you need to detect? The question is too general. You need to know what you looking for, to have a way of detecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the video tag support is quite easy:

```
if (typeof HTMLVideoElement == 'function') {
  alert('<video> tag supported');
}
```

That's in my opinion a simplistic version. Here is how the many times mentioned `modernizr` does it, which is a bit more bullet proof probably:

```
function supportsVideo() {
        var elem = document.createElement('video'),
            bool = false;

        // IE9 Running on Windows Server SKU can cause an exception to be thrown, bug #224
        try {
            if ( bool = !!elem.canPlayType ) {
                bool      = new Boolean(bool);
                bool.ogg  = elem.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora"');

                // Workaround required for IE9, which doesn't report video support without audio codec specified.
                //   bug 599718 @ msft connect
                var h264 = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E';
                bool.h264 = elem.canPlayType(h264 + '"') || elem.canPlayType(h264 + ', mp4a.40.2"');

                bool.webm = elem.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"');
            }

        } catch(e) { }

        return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to detect HTML5 and CSS features.

Answer (score 2):

As the other suggested the best option is to use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), because it was created especially to do this work.

I don't know any plugin in jQuery that covers this functionality (jQuery.supports doesn't check much) but if you want you could try [mooModernizr](http://www.aryweb.nl/projects/mooModernizr/) witch extends MooTools `Browser.Features` object

Another completely valid option is to check Modernizrs source code, and implment that with the features you want to detect.

Answer (score 1):

Check out modernizr.  It is an open source javascript library that specializes in  detection of html5 / css3 features:
http://www.modernizr.com/